# unable to access the web api after published to Beanstalk AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have published my web api app from visual studio to AWS Beanstalk, however I couldn't access my application and I got the error as showing in the image below.[image]

The AWS Beanstalk is configured as below:

```
  {
    "comment" : "This file is used to help set default values when using the dotnet CLI extension 
    Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Tools. For more information run \"dotnet eb --help\" from the project 
    root.",
   "profile" : "default",
   "region"  : "ca-central-1",
   "application" : "eBookCatalog",
  "environment" : "eBookCatalog-dev",
  "cname"       : "ebookcatalog-dev",
  "solution-stack" : "64bit Windows Server Core 2016 v2.6.0 running IIS 10.0",
  "environment-type" : "SingleInstance",
  "instance-profile" : "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role",
  "service-role"     : "aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role",
  "health-check-url" : "/",
  "instance-type"    : "t2.micro",
  "key-pair"         : "eBookCatalog",
  "iis-website"      : "Default Web Site",
  "app-path"         : "/",
  "enable-xray"      : false
 }
```

The environment status as showing below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not EB issue, but your application. If you check it cerefully using `curl` for instance, you get response from your `Microsoft-IIS/10.0` server. So connection works as expected. Maybe your application requires a path, `ebookcatalog-dev.ca-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api` or it is invoked by some other non-default way.

```
curl -i ebookcatalog-dev.ca-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: That's true. Do you know if it is possible for me to change "ebookcatalog-dev.ca-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"  TO "ebookcatalog-dev.ca-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api" from  Elastic Beanstalk? For now I only get the correct url by adding "/api"

Comment: @Tasneem Sadly I don't know `Microsoft-IIS/10.0` well enough to advise how to change it for different path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will search on that.